# I am getting caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Link') even though Link is defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint

[Items returned from Ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oePLx.jpg)I am getting `caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Link')` on the console even though it is defined in the Sharepoint List

```
    var build_newQuickLinks = function (items) {
        var newQuickLinksSection = $("#quickLinkItems");
        
        console.log(newQuickLinksSection)
        //var start = Math.max(0, items.length - 4);
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        
         let quickLinks = items[i].Link != null ? 
          '<a target="_blank" href='+ items[i].Link.Url +' class="btn btn-tag btn-rounded" data-mdb-close="true">' +
                '<div class="d-flex align-items-center align-content-center justify-content-left"><i class="'+ items[i].Icon +'"></i><span class="text-truncate">'+ items[i].Title +'</span></div></a>'
: ''
newQuickLinksSection.append(quickLinks);
    
        }
    
    }
    
    //ajax call
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrlQuickLinks,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = data.d.results;
                console.log(items)
                // only check out the data here. like, Array.isArray(items)
                // call different function to do
                build_newQuickLinks(items);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error: " + data);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the Javascript code I am using to call the list in Sharepoint. I tried changing `null` to `undefined` but I still get the same result. The items are displaying on the page as intended but I still get that message in the console.

```
https://www.broward.org/playground/carlos/Pages/Demo-2.aspx
```